# "Let's bring it down in scale a bit", What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Context (Source: History of the world by Andrew Marr - Episode 8)

***This is a big story*** (The author indicates the Atomic bombing of Hiroshima)*. **Let's try and bring it down in scale a bit.***

It made me feel like it means "let's analyze (or let's talk) about it a little bit". After that, the author showed how people died in the World War Atomic bomb in Hiroshima.

*This is a woman's watch, hands fused to the time of the blast. Around 400 young children were here with their ten teachers when the bomb went off, and all but one was burned to death immediately. In a three-mile radius of the blast, almost everybody suffered fatal burns,..*

I've look up the phrase "Bring sth down" in many dictionaries but the meanings they  give didn't fit to the documentary.

Comment: Let's make it smaller(simpler) and more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

To 'bring down in scale' is to make smaller.. so the author could mean to give you a quicker/simpler and shortened version, or he could intend to give you one perspective/one point of view as a way of providing a short example of what the 'bigger picture' might be like

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of horror if one ponders how many people died. The mind cannot comprehend; it can scarcely imagine. But to make it personal -- to bring it to a smaller scale -- this can be comprehended.

This is why the narrative talked about the four hundred children. These four hundred souls represent a smaller scale than fifty thousand, and the smaller scale helps make the atomic bomb more comprehensible.